# tmux: what is the mode I get periodically locked in when (attempting) pressing Ctrl-B Z

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I am quite new to tmux (but familarized with the basics).

Regularly, I end up in a mode, I do not understand, and I do not know how to leave anymore. This happens sometimes when having multiple panes and trying to zoom by pressing Ctrl-B Z. At least, this is my intention when it happens, I guess I do something wrong, like pressing other keys accidentally.

In this mode, I get an empty screen (which I can type text in), without any tmux commands working. It seems that every control sequence is escaped, pressing Ctrl-B brings up a `^B` on the screen, instead of being interpreted as start of a command.

Any idea, what mode this is, which I am regulary locked in?

**Additions, as answer for comments:**
I also did a lot of tests to reproduce this intentionally, but I did not manage to do so.

I am working on CentOS7, and tmux is executed locally. SSH does not need to be involved to make this happen.

My best guess is that I am in a special mode (like scroll/edit mode, maybe some vi-like special mode?) or maybe I am pressing Ctrl-Z instead of Ctrl-B Z. But as I did not manage to reproduce by will, this is just guessing.

Comment: I tried every combination of CTRL-B <Key> for keys around Z, but I couldn't replicate your issue, what version of Tmux are you using? What distro of Linux? Are you connecting via SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it was the Ctrl-S/Ctrl-Q issue, which are used to turn input off/on in terminals:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal